# JPA and Postgres generate_series

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, generate-series

I have problem with JPA. I start with something like that (I have reduced the query to a fragment that causes an error):

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from generate_series(:from::date, :to, '1 day') as dt").setParameter("from", from).setParameter("to", to).getResultList();
```

and have "Not all named parameters have been set" error. I found that I should change it to something like that:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from generate_series (date :from, :to, '1 day') as dt")...
```

or

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from generate_series (cast (:from as date), :to, '1 day') as dt")...
```

I tried also positional parameters:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from generate_series (cast (?1 as date), ?2, '1 day') as dt")...
```

Unfortunately, it did not help. I would ask for some suggestions on how you can solve this problem. I use Hibernate.

Comment: JPA Native queries support POSITIONAL parameters only. Any NAMED parameter is not guaranteed to be supported by the JPA implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I forgot to mention but I try use positional parameters and this also did not work.

Comment: So update your question using positional parameters and define what is "did not work" in that case, and perhaps mention which JPA implementation because such behaviour is clearly implementation dependent

Comment: still doesn't say what happened when you used positional params ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the lack of response. I change to positional parameters and date to timestamp, my ide (IntelliJ IDEA) still shows an error "Cannot resolve query parameter" but when i deploy it on server its work.

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from generate_series(cast (?1 as TIMESTAMP), cast(?2 as TIMESTAMP), '1 day'").setParameter(1, from).setParameter(2, to).getResultList();
```